# How to evaluate $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty } \frac{\ln(a+be^x)}{\sqrt{a+bx^2}} =? $

Tags: calculus

Suppose $b>0$

$\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty } \frac{\ln(a+be^x)}{\sqrt{a+bx^2}} =? $

I know that this is an indetermination of the form $\infty / \infty$ . I tried to use L'Hôpital, but I didn't find the answer.

Comment: Can you include in your post what you got after your first application of L'hospital's rule?

Comment: Hint:

$$\ln(a+be^{x})=\ln [e^x(ae^{-x}+b)]=x+\ln[ae^{-x}+b]$$

Comment: The result is $\large \frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}$

Comment: @Peter what if $b = 0$?

Comment: ^^If $b=0$ then the function itself becomes constant as a function of $x$

Comment: Ok, in this case we have $\large \frac{ln(a)}{\sqrt{a}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @Mario G suggestion:

$ln(a+be^x) = x + ln (ae^{-x} +b)$

And, 
$\sqrt{a+bx^{2}} = x\sqrt{a/x^2 +b}$

So, the quotient can be written as:
$\frac{x + ln (ae^{-x} +b)}{x\sqrt{a/x^2 +b}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{a/x^2 +b}} + \frac{ln(ae^{-x} +b)}{{x\sqrt{a/x^2 +b}}}$

when $x \rightarrow +\infty$ ,
$a/x^2 \rightarrow 0$ and $ae^{-x} \rightarrow 0$

So,$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{a/x^2 +b}} + \frac{ln(ae^{-x} +b)}{{x\sqrt{a/x^2 +b}}} \rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{b}} + \frac{1}{x} . \frac{ln b }{\sqrt{b}} \rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}$
when $x \rightarrow +\infty$

Answer (score 1):

here is what you can do without l'hospital. 
$ \ln(a+be^x) = \ln(be^x) + \cdots = x + \ln(b) + \cdots$ and 
$\sqrt{a + bx^2} = x\sqrt b + \cdots$ so the 
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{\ln(a + be^x)}{\sqrt{a + bx^2}} = \lim_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{x + \ln(b) + \cdots}{ x\sqrt b + \cdots} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt b}$$